# Validation issues deploying from local machine's IIS 5.1 to Web Server's IIS 6.0

Tags: validation

I'm developing a VB.NET 1.1 web application. All validation and RegEx controls work perfectly when testing on my *local* machine using IIS 5.1, however when I deploy to our "leased" web server utilizing IIS 6.0 I'm either getting a "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error on the date fields (worked on local machine), or the other non-date validation and RegEx controls do not get recognized until after submtting the form, in which the data had somehow already posted to the database by this time.

I was not aware that I would be using a different version of IIS once deploying into the testing/production environment, and higher-up help is nonexistent or less knowledgeable.

I've added the dumbed-down and longer-written conditional logic to bypass this validation issue for the meantime because I'm not having much luck googling the *proper* resolution, nor finding it here yet. Please advise on what I may be missing out on knowledge-wise with validation or perhaps what the functional differences between IIS 5.1 and 6.0 would be that I may look further into.

I apologize if this is too broad of an issue description, my mind is malf-helted by now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot remember the exact specifics on this, and I might have to go digging deep to try and find it.  But the root cause is due to a slightly different build number on the .NET 1.1 framework between your local machine to the actual production web server.

I had this issue a few years ago, we synced the .NET patches, and we got it to work